# Can't install packages in RStudio - blocked after download

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I'm trying to install the package "sqldf" in RStudio but it blocks after downloading few packages

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)


> install.packages("sqldf")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/sperga/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘BH’, ‘plogr’, ‘gsubfn’, ‘proto’, ‘RSQLite’, ‘DBI’, ‘chron’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/BH_1.66.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17880019 bytes (17.1 MB)
downloaded 17.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/plogr_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 18718 bytes (18 KB)
downloaded 18 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/gsubfn_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 357663 bytes (349 KB)
downloaded 349 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/proto_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 471954 bytes (460 KB)
downloaded 460 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/RSQLite_2.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2154846 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/DBI_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 887210 bytes (866 KB)
downloaded 866 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/chron_2.3-52.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 198130 bytes (193 KB)
downloaded 193 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/sqldf_0.4-11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 78155 bytes (76 KB)
downloaded 76 KB
```

I also tried to shitch the CRAN but it didn't work.

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'blocks'? Does it pause after showing that output, and for how long? It would also be useful to see error messages, if you get any.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem, but I loaded the RGui, ran it as administrator, typed the install command (install.packages("ez") for me), and just let it run. After about 10 solid minutes it finished. Could be you're just not waiting long enough.